# If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then is $A^TAx = A^Tb$ always consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found this True/False question in a previous exam.

I did this: $$A^TAx = A^Tb$$ $$ \iff A^T(Ax - b) = 0$$
How to continue?

Comment: The key fact is that ${\cal R} A^T = {\cal R}(A^T A)$.

Comment: @copper.hat can you elaborate?

Comment: If you accept my statement (don't :-)) then there must be some $x$ such that the equation holds.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Normal Equation.Following is simplest argument that I know. $$A^{T}A\textbf{x} = A^{T}\textbf{b}$$

$ \exists \textbf{x}$ that satisfies above equation  $\iff$ $\text{span} \{ A^{T} \textbf{b} \}  \subset \text{Colspace}[A^TA] \iff \text{Colspace}[A^TA]^{\perp} \subset \text{span}\{A^{T}b\}^{\perp}  $

So this reduces showing that, if something is orthogonal to columspace of $A^T A$ then it should be orthogonal to  span of $A^T\textbf{b}$. Now orthogonal complement of columnspace is left null space . so

$$\textbf{z} \in \text{Colspace}[A^TA]^{\perp} \iff  \textbf{z}^{T}(A^{T}A) = \textbf{0} \implies\textbf{z}^{T}A^TA\textbf{z} = 0  \implies \textbf{z}^{T}A^{T} = \textbf{0} \implies \textbf{z}^TA^{T} \textbf{b} = 0 \implies \text{$\textbf{z}$ is orthogonal to $A^{T}\textbf{b}$}$$

some of justification used are  $\textbf{z}^{T}A^TA\textbf{z} = ||\textbf{z}^{T}A^{T}||$ and norm is zero *iff* vector is $\textbf{0}$ , last but one implication comes from multiplying $\textbf{b}$ on both side.Hence we have  shown that $\text{Colspace}[A^TA]^{\perp} \subset \text{span}\{A^{T}\textbf{b}\}^{\perp}$ and we are done.

The only time we used $\textbf{b}$ was at last. So,we can  multiply arbitrary $\textbf{b}$ and so result holds for arbitrary $\textbf{b}$